# How to have multi line cell in React data grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

Currently using react-data-grid and it only shows a single line text, however I am trying to display multi line text.

sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/5vy2q8owj4?from-embed

Answer (score 3):

```
 getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
```

> It will break lines automaticaly in mui DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You can override the data-grid cell content class to your file.

**Render:**

```
<div class="react-grid-multiline-content">
  <ReactDataGrid columns={columns} rowGetter={i => rows[i]} rowsCount={rows.length}/>
</div>
```

**Style:**

```
.react-grid-multiline-content .react-grid-Cell__value {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've just updated the sandbox but it still seems to be doing the same thing as it is not showing multi lines.

maybe I put the code in incorrectly? 
Updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-z5sen?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you add the more data to your cell content

Comment: oh cool, it works, I just had to store it an a array. Its just when I want to edit it on click it won't store the value as a multi line is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Yes, you can add/remove the class from the element when You click on edit button using dynamic class. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar problem by resetting the cells' `line-height` CSS property.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

My columns:

```
  const columns: Column<MyRow>[] = [
    {
      key: "id",
      name: "ID"
    },
    {
      key: "addressSummary",
      name: "Address",
      formatter: (formatterProps) => <AddressBlock {...formatterProps.row} />,
      cellClass: "normalLineHeight" // Need to reset the line height on affected cells
    }
  ];
```

CSS:

```
.normalLineHeight {
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Here is the sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-data-grid-multi-line-content-fix-u6im0